# I've placed a CSV file in hdfs and formatted the namenode but when I try to list the hdfs' contents, I don't see the file

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a CSV file named `data.csv` that I've placed in my `/hdfs/namenode` directory by scp'ing it from my local machine to the namenode which is an ec2 instance on AWS.  I formatted the namenode using the command `hdfs namenode -format` and I didn't receive any `warning` or `error` messages, only `info` messages (which is a good thing - I think that means the formatting worked).  I believe that the hdfs now contains my file `data.csv`.  However, when I run the command `hdfs dfs -ls /`, I get the following output:

```
Found 1 items
drwx------   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-11-18 01:40 /tmp
```

Shouldn't my `data.csv` file be present in the hdfs?

This is my first time experimenting with hadoop and AWS so I apologize if this is common sense.  I saw similar questions asked but didn't see a solution that made sense to me.  Please feel free to ask for additional details I might have accidentally missed or forgotten.  Thanks!

Comment: you need to use "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal srcfile destfile" or "hdfs dfs -put" instead of scp. Morever scp'ing the file in hdfs/namenode is not going to put the file on Hadoop file system.

Comment: I tried both of those commands, and in each case, `hdfs dfs -ls /` results in no change and the file has not been added to the hdfs. Any further suggestions?